# How to add marker on react-native-maps. Documentation is not clear enough for beginners

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base, react-native-maps

How can we add marker in a specific area if the code looks like something like this? Documentation is not enough clear for beginners.

```
<View style={{marginTop:20, width:null, height:200}}>  
   <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1,width:null, height:200 }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      />   
      </View>
```

How can it be included in this code?

Comment: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps#rendering-a-list-of-markers-on-a-map ?

Comment: Yes react-native-maps

Comment: No. Check the example on the link. It shows pretty clear how to create Markers.,

Comment: Just put this? instead of above code?

<Marker coordinate={marker.latlng}>
  <MyCustomMarkerView {...marker} />
</Marker>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<View style={{marginTop:20, width:null, height:200}}>  
   <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1,width:null, height:200 }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}>
      <Marker coordinate={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,}} >
        </Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
```

you have to just put the marker in your mapview and pass the 
latitiude-longitude of the location where you want to put your marker